# Get all text from body and split based on tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, split, element

I am creating an application in which I have a scenario where I am translating my whole page text, now I want to get the text from the page,

I can simply get the text by `$('body').text()`

but in my scenario, I want to get all the text and split it when there is a any tag end

like the below example

```js
console.log($('#test').text().split('\n'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <p>Testing p</p>
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" />
  <h1>M</h1>
  <span>w</span><span>a</span><span>k</span><span>a</span>
  <p><span>new s</span></p>
  <div>a</div>
  <h6>d</h6>
</div>
```

my result is coming like below

```
[
  "",
  "  Testing p",
  "  ",
  "  M",
  "  waka",
  "  new s",
  "  a",
  "  d",
  ""
]
```

but I want my result to be like

```
[
  "",
  "  Testing p",
  "  ",
  "  M",
  "  w",
  "  a",
  "  k",
  "  a",
  "  new s",
  "  a",
  "  d",
  ""
]
```

how can I achieve this?
and sorry for grammatical mistakes.

Comment: @CertainPerformance no sir it is not required

Comment: Do you need the empty node after `Testing p`? If not, this becomes a simple recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you require you can use a recursive function to traverse through all the elements within a given container and retrieve the values from their text nodes.

The only inconsistency with your desired output is with the empty nodes, of which your example above includes some, but not all. You'd need to implement some logic to determine which ones you want to remove and which to keep. As you state this is for translation purposes, I'd suggest discounting them all, as there's nothing there to be translated. With all that said, try this:

```js
function getText(el, arr) {
  arr = arr || [];

  for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var node = el.childNodes[i];
    if (node.nodeType === 1) 
      getText(node, arr);
    else if (node.nodeType === 3 && node.nodeValue.trim())
      arr.push(node.nodeValue);

    // version of above which includes empty nodes:
    /*
      else if (node.nodeType === 3)
        arr.push(node.nodeValue);
    */ 
  }

  return arr;
}

var textValues = getText(document.getElementById('test'));
console.log(textValues);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <p>Testing p</p>
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" />
  <h1>M</h1>
  <span>w</span><span>a</span><span>k</span><span>a</span>
  <p><span>new s</span></p>
  <div>a</div>
  <h6>d</h6>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method

```js
let result = $('#test')
  .children()
  .map(function() {
    return $(this).text()
  })
  .get()

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  <p>Testing p</p>
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" />
  <h1>M</h1>
  <span>w</span><span>a</span><span>k</span><span>a</span>
  <p><span>new s</span></p>
  <div>a</div>
  <h6>d</h6>
</div>
```

Comment: It wont work if my div contains any text or I have multiple chilldren of a tag

Comment: @IbrahimShaikh `multiple chilldren of a tag` i cant get you?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, you could get the `children()` and use `text()` callback for this like:

```js
let arr = [];

$('#test').children().text(function(i,t){
    arr.push(t);
});

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  <p>Testing p</p>
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" />
  <h1>M</h1>
  <span>w</span><span>a</span><span>k</span><span>a</span>
  <p><span>new s</span></p>
  <div>a</div>
  <h6>d</h6>
</div>
```

Another way to go is by using `map()` for this and check the `children()` of the current element like:

```js
let arr = $('#test *').map(function(i, s) {
  if (!$(s).children().length)
    return $(s).text()
}).get();

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <p>Testing p</p>
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" />
  <h1>M</h1>
  <span>w</span><span>a</span><span>k</span><span>a</span>
  <p><span>new s</span></p>
  <div>a</div>
  <h6>d</h6>
</div>
```

Comment: It wont work if my div contains any text or I have multiple chilldren of a tag

Comment: We've provided answers to your posted question and you can see that our outputs fit the posted desired output in your OP, if you've other cases you must post them in your question or post another question with your specific cases.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea. What if we used a regular expression for this? I have prepared a jsfiddle for this, have a look at it and maybe you can adapt it for yourself too.

https://jsfiddle.net/js73hb2d/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var bodyHtml = $("body").html();
  var regex = /(<[^>]+>)+(.*?)(<\/\w*>)+/g;
  var matches = regex.exec(bodyHtml);
  var splitText = [];
  while (matches != null) {
    splitText.push(matches[2]);
    matches = regex.exec(bodyHtml);
  }
  alert(splitText);
});
```